# How does the Axiom of Foundation apply?

Tags: set-theory

> There is no set $x$ such that $x=\{\{\{x\}\}\}$.

I am aware the axiom of foundation comes can be applied since clearly $x$ is non empty. Thus we have an element call it $y \in x$. The only element in $x$ is $\{\{x\}\}$, and we have $\{\{x\}\}=y$, now we have $y \cap \{y\} = \emptyset$. It follows that $y \notin y$.

Comment: what are you asking?

Comment: I am unsure if my application will get me to the desired result.

Comment: Your approach isn't going anywhere helpful.  You'll need to more cleverly choose a set to apply the axiom of foundation to.

Comment: The axiom of foundation says that ***EVERY*** nonempty set is disjoint from one of its elements. If $x=\{\{\{x\}\}\}$ let $y=\{x\}$ and  let $z=\{y\};$ then $x\in y\in z\in x.$ What about the nonempty set $A=\{x,y,z\}$? Which element of $A$ is disjoint from $A?$

Comment: By the below answer I see that none of the elements are disjoint from A.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider the set $E = \{x, \{x\}, \{\{x\}\}\}$

There exists $y \in E$ such that $y\cap E = \emptyset$. But

If $y = x = \{\{\{x\}\}\}$, $y \cap E = \{\{\{x\}\}\} \neq \emptyset$

If $y = \{x\}$, $y \cap E = \{x\} \neq \emptyset$

If $y= \{\{x\}\}$, $y\cap E = \{\{x\}\} \neq \emptyset$

Contradiction

Comment: Sorry, but how does this apply to my situation?

Comment: @ElSpiffy: It's a contradiction, derived from the assumption $x = \{\{\{x\}\}\}$.

Comment: To the proposer. We use the axioms of Pairing and Union to show that $E$ exists. And the axiom of Extensionality (a.k.a.Regularity) is implicitly used also.